# How to fasten one pipe to another under sink

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water

See attached picture. I have a pipe that is inserted into an expanded pipe. Problem is, sometimes the expanded pipe slips down, spraying water everywhere. How would I go about keeping the expanded pipe held up?
[image: picture of pipes]

Answer (score 1):

Both the pipe connections on the vertical pipe run in your picture (the one with the nut and the threaded one which is missing the nut) are designed as *slip-joint* connections. They utilize a rubber or plastic *slip-joint washer* that squeezes down on the inserted pipe when the *slip-joint nut* is tightened.

The assembly coming down from the sink is called a *pop-up drain assembly* and it has a 1 1/4" *tailpiece* pipe that you cannot see in your picture because it is inserted entirely into the 1 1/2" *slip-joint extension* which, by the way, is the piece that is missing its slip-joint nut).

You will need to get a couple parts from the plumbing shop: (1) 1 1/2" x 1 1/4" slip-joint nut; and (1) 1 1/2" x 1 1/4" slip-joint washer (rubber or plastic, don't matter)

Then you need to do **exactly** this:

- remove the trap *u-bend* at the bottom
- remove the 1 1/2" slip-joint extension and cut it down 1"
- slide an 1 1/2" x 1 1/4" slip-joint nut up onto the 1 1/4" tailpiece, followed by an 1 1/2" x 1 1/4" slip joint washer
- slide the (now 1" shorter) 1 1/2" slip-joint extension up onto the 1 1/4" tailpiece and hand tighten the nut and washer, from the previous step, to the threaded top of it
- slide the trap u-bend back up into place
- wiggle everything about until it's straight and clean
- tighten all slip-joint nuts with a wrench, not too tight but more than hand-tight.

It should look something like this when you are done:

[image]